# Json out put with PHP

Tags: php, json

At the moment i m getting the json out put as below

```
[    
    {
        "ID": 1479,
        "Name": "praven",
        "Number": "007",
        "Image": ""
    }
]
```

at the moment the PHP code i m using to generate this code as below

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/connectionInfoTest.php');


//Set up our connection
$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
{
    //Connection failed
    echo 'No Connection';
}

else
{
    //Create query to retrieve all contacts
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM Contacts ORDER BY Contacts_ID';

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

    if (!$stmt)
    {
        //Query failed
        echo 'Query failed';
    }

    else
    {
        $contacts = array(); //Create an array to hold all of the contacts
        //Query successful, begin putting each contact into an array of contacts

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //While there are still contacts
        {
            //Create an associative array to hold the current contact
            //the names must match exactly the property names in the contact class in our C# code.
            $contact= array("ID" => $row['Contacts_ID'],
                             "Name" => $row['Contacts_Name'],
                             "Number" => $row['Contacts_Number'],
                             "Image" => base64_encode($row['Contacts_Image'])
                             );

            //Add the contact to the contacts array
            array_push($contacts, $contact);
        }

        //Echo out the contacts array in JSON format
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($contacts,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
?>
```

but the problem is the the out put i m expecting is as below

```
{   
    "contacts": [{   
        "ID": 1452,
         "Name": "John",
         "Number": "1452",
         "Image": ""
       }]   
}
```

So what should i cange in the PHP to get the expecting out put i m expecting? THANKS.

Comment: echo json_encode(['contacts'=>$contacts],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

Replace your code here:

```
//Echo out the contacts array in JSON format
header('Content-type: application/json');
$output = ['contacts' => $contacts];
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks , out put is executing as i expected thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    $contacts = array(); //Create an array to hold all of the contacts
    //Query successful, begin putting each contact into an array of contacts

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //While there are still contacts
    {
        //Create an associative array to hold the current contact
        //the names must match exactly the property names in the contact class in our C# code.
        $contacts[] = array("ID" => $row['Contacts_ID'],
                         "Name" => $row['Contacts_Name'],
                         "Number" => $row['Contacts_Number'],
                         "Image" => base64_encode($row['Contacts_Image'])
                         );

    }

    //Echo out the contacts array in JSON format
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['contacts' => $contacts],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```